# Setting up Apache 2 Local Development Environment & Permissions

Tags: permissions, apache-httpd

I frequently find myself encountering problems (usually permissions) when trying to setup a local development server. Or creating a new site (alias).

Very common problem is I need to allow `www-data` (Apache use on ubuntu) access to all directories leading to the working directory.

Another problem is since I am logged in as my personal user `jiewmeng`, when I create new files, they are owned by me, and sometimes, Apache can't read/write to it.

How is your local development setup like? I am using Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I frequently find myself encountering problems (usually permissions)

That rather implies that you haven't got a permissions model in place.

> How is your local development setup like?

I use the 'other' entity to allow access for the apache uid, the 'group' is for the people who need to deploy / edit files and the user is the user whom created the files.

So my files look something like:

```
drwxrwsr-x symcbean webdev  webroot/
-rw-rw-r-- other    webdev  webroot/a.php
-rw-rw-r-- symcbean webdev  webroot/b.php
drwxrwxrwx symcbean webdev  webroot/data
-rw-rw-rw- apache   apache  webroot/data/stuff.txt
drwxrwsr-x symcbean webdev  webroot/include/
-rw-rw-r-- symcbean webdev  webroot/include/def.php
```

Comment: I am new to Linux, so I still learning as I go. So when I create new users, I should do something like `adduser {username} --gid www-data` to make the files they create under the `www-data` group (then apache can see those)? For existing users, I'd do `usermod --gid www-data {username}`? Is `gid` meant for that? I was wondering how can I have files I create under `www-data`

Comment: For existing users, do **not** forget the `--append` option or you clear all groups

Comment: Oh then do you have all your files in web root. I think another problem I need to allow `www-data` I think `rwx` access on parent folders all the way down to the project. Perhaps in a production environment I can put all my files in web root, but in development, I think its better to put them in the data drive, or `/projects`. Also when using frameworks, I think its a good practice to have my application files outside webroot

Comment: To clarify, @JiewMeng, I don't think @@symcbean was saying anything about adding `{username}` to `www-dev`. That is _one_ way of doing it, but not what @@symcbean was suggesting. @@syncbean was suggesting that you create a _new group_ called `webdev` so that others users as well can be added to that group. Then, if you group-own all files and folders by `webdev`, all your users can edit those files. How does apache aka `www-data` access the files it needs? That's what he meant by "other" permissions (aka "world" permissions)—the last triad—as long as apache can read files and

Comment: read/execute directories, that's all it needs. (Even for things like PHP files, Apache only needs to be able to _read_ them.) In @@symcbean's model, the significant thing is the *sticky bit* on the directories (notice the `s` in lieu of `x`) that instructs new files and directories to inherit its group. And _that's_ how your users continue to have access to files and directories as they get created. Finally, you notice there's a directory without an `s`, and a file in it owned by `apache` aka `www-data`. That's an example of how you'd configure an "uploads" folder—@@symcbean calls it "data."

Comment: Where would you store your projects? /var/opt/ or in your home dir?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Solution 1 (the setgid method) described on [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/a/46371/6969) This has as advantage that I can read files created by Apache and the other way round.

Comment: So all your scripts / content is writeable by the webserver uid?

Comment: @symcbean It's readable only unless I manually `chmod g+w` a file or directory.